# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'addNewMessageToPage' of undefined - signalr with proxy

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am working to get a signalr proxy working. I have the hub in one project and need to call on its actions from another:

In my javascript in the project without the hub I have this:

```
    var hubConnection = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
    var chat = hubConnection.createHubProxy('ticketHub');


    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://local.serving/TouchScreen/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

When I run this I get:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'addNewMessageToPage' of undefined

My TouchScreen project has a hub called TicketHub with the following:

```
public class TicketHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```

Both projects have startup.cs files and neither are showing any further errors.

When I look to my network traffic, I see that this file returns 200 ok:

```
<script src="http://local.serving/TouchScreen/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Am I wrong with my proxy setup here as it all seems to follow as far as I can see.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to local.serving/signalr/hubs to make sure the hub isn't being created at the root.